# AWS access the internet through another VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have two VPCs - A and  B. VPC A is our main VPC and our Firewall with VPN is located in this VPC. VPC B has no outside subnet. I can connect to any instance in VPC A when I'm connected through the VPN. I have a VPC peering between vpc A and B. From instance in VPC A I can connect to any instance in VPC B.

PROBLEM:

I am trying to connect (ssh) to an instance in VPC B using the VPN in VPC A and it doesnt work.

VPC A routing table- default pointing to Firewall, dest to VPC B has peering connection as target.

VPC B - default is set to peering connection with VPC A.

For testing I have all sec groups wide open.

Comment: You will still need a NAT for VPC B even if you are trying to connect through a VPN from VPC A

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are using VPC peering , then it doesn't allow passthrough connection.
   It is stated under AWS [invalid peering configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/invalid-peering-configurations.html) . You may try using SSH tunneling, but I can't guarantee it will works.
2. If NOT using VPC peering, there is no way you can connect two VPC without a VLAN and routing in between.

Comment: thansk!... so If I want to create UAT and PROD in different VPCs and I wanted to have only one set of firewalls in one VPC and route traffic from the firewall to the other VPC i can't? that's a rather big limitation, isn't it?

Comment: Well, it is no different than putting system in isolated LAN in the first place. So you need to decide whether you want total or partial isolation.